# How to access USB disk from terminal

Tags: directory, hard-disk, usb-drive, cd-command, open-files

I have few files in a USB disk named `F:`. I The files inside it are large. I do not want to move them to my harddisk. I want to make some comparison, e.g. `diff` between files from inside the USB and in the disk.

The problem is I am unable to know the USB disk path or how to access it? It seems under the root directory. But when I type `cd F` to go inside the F I get error:

```
bash: cd: F:: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT:** 
I use Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

Comment: Naming drives with letters (C, D, F) is a Windows thing. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/464200/edit) your question with details of what Unix or Linux operating system you're using. To view the contents of the USB drive you will need to `mount` the device, which many OSes will automatically do for you.

Answer (score 3):

As has already been said in the comment, your disk isn't "named `F:`". `F` is just the drive letter that gets assigned to it under Windows.

A bit of background: The USB disk will show up as an USB device (see a list of them with `lsusb`) when connected; the USB storage interface of your disk will show up as a SCSI device (see a list of them with `lsscsi`),  the OS will create a block device for it (`/dev/sdX`, where `X` is the next free letter) and block devices for all partitions (`/dev/sdXN`, where `N` is a number), and you will get symlinks to these devices using various bits of other information under `/dev/disk/by-*`. An equivalent thing happens under Windows (but the user doesn't notice).

I'll assume that your Ubuntu has some working kind of automounter, and in that case the it will assign some file path to it under which you can access the contents of your disk. You can see all mounted devices with `mount`, look for your disk among them (or look at the difference between the outputs with and without the USB drive connected).

I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu Desktop, but probably it will appear under `/media/some_other_name`. If it doesn't, you explicitly need to `mount` it. In that case, you'll have to choose a directory.

Once you know the path where it is mounted, you can `cd` into it as usual.